# Planetscale post request error 'client must use SSL/TLS'

Tags: mysql, express, ssl, heroku

Using tools

1. Planetscale MySQL cloud database
2. Express
3. Swagger
4. Heroku

I tried to send a post request to server from postman and swagger api doc.
But I got this error for both.

```
unknown error: Code: UNAVAILABLE
server does not allow insecure connections, client must use SSL/TLS
```

I could send post requests when using localhost. But after deploying app on heroku, I cannot do that anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/) explain how to load the [certificates](https://docs.planetscale.com/concepts/secure-connections)

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'mysql',
    username: MYSQL_USER,
    password: MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    host: MYSQL_HOST,
    dialectOptions: {
        bigNumberStrings: true,
        ssl: {
          ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ca-certificates.crt')
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: where do I download `ca-certificates.crt` from?

Comment: from [here](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html) and rename the file to **ca-certificates.crt**

Comment: i have question. why planetscale do not allow alter table? when using sequelize model?

Answer (score 2):

The quicker solution would be:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  "DATABASE_NAME",
  "USERNAME",
  "PASSWORD",
  {
    host: "HOST",
    dialect: "mysql",
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
      },
    },
    define: {
      timestamps: false,
    },
  }
);
```

With this we don't need to import certificate.

Comment: Hi my friend could you convert it to PRISMA and .ENV please????